# Any method to undraw a portion of batcher.draw past a certain point in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

so currently I've learned that batcher.draw can draw an asset on to the screen. It can be used to draw a moving asset off the screen.

I was wondering if there was anyway to have the asset drawn to be partially undrawn if it crosses a certain x value (if half of the drawn texture crosses the x value, then only the half that didn't cross would be rendered), thus simulating the effect of moving an asset off the screen.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean clipping, so something along the lines of what is suggested [here on the wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Clipping,-with-the-use-of-scissorstack).

```
Rectangle scissors = new Rectangle();
Rectangle clipBounds = new Rectangle(x,y,w,h);
ScissorStack.calculateScissors(camera, spriteBatch.getTransformMatrix(), clipBounds, scissors);
ScissorStack.pushScissors(scissors);
spriteBatch.draw(...); // Replace this with your limited drawing code
spriteBatch.flush();
ScissorStack.popScissors();
```

This will draw only things which are inside of the clipBounds rectangle.